# iphone : how to copy images to image group?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, resources

I just drag and drop image to image group but when I run this code to other machine it gives errors of all the images.

I want to know that how do I copy them so that to other machine it do not give errors.

[image]

Comment: Are the images in the directory? can you find them if you open the dir you copied to the other machine? When you drag & drop you should selected the "copy" checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the checkbox on top and it will copy the resource on destination.

[image]